# Error: "OutputStartTime should not be specified if the start mode has been defined as JobStartTime"

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-stream-analytics

I have created a template of two resources from the Azure Portal. I created it from the resource group.
The resources created are an event hubs and a Stream analytics job.

When deploying from the Azure portal (using the "New Resource" option) I get an error in the Stream Analytics job.

The error is as follows: "OutputStartTime should not be specified if the start mode has been defined as JobStartTime"

And this is the section where the parameter that gives the error is:

```
        "type": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs",
        "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
        "name": "[parameters('streamingjobs_rtjobstream1_name')]",
        "location": "West Europe",
        "properties": {
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard"
            },
            "outputStartMode": "JobStartTime",
            "outputStartTime": "2020-03-09T10:49:29.56Z",
            "eventsOutOfOrderPolicy": "Adjust",
            "outputErrorPolicy": "Stop",
            "eventsOutOfOrderMaxDelayInSeconds": 0,
            "eventsLateArrivalMaxDelayInSeconds": 5,
            "dataLocale": "en-US",
            "compatibilityLevel": "1.1"
```

How can I solve that?

Thanks in advance

Hi @Joey Cai
Thank you very much for your answer.
I have tried deleting the two properties, but now it gives me several errors.
Almost all errors are due to the API version.
I also made that change, and now it gives me other errors:

"details ": [{" code ":" 422 "," message ":" {\ r \ n \ "code \": \ "422 \", \ r \ n \ " message \ ": \" The required 'password' property is missing in the request. \ ", {" code ":" 422 "

I do not understand, because if the template has been generated from the resources already created, I receive all these errors.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try removing "outputStartTime"?

Comment: You could refer to this article to [create Stream Analytics Job](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-streamanalytics-create).

Comment: I have reviewed the link you included but unfortunately I had already seen it and had discarded it because it does not include the most important thing that are the inputs, the outputs and the query.
Although my initial idea was not to create a template from 0, but to use the automatic generation of the template provided by the portal. Is there any other example that can guide me to create a template for this resource and that includes the inputs, outputs and the query?

Comment: You could refer to this [article](https://pnagarjuna.wordpress.com/2017/11/24/arm-template-for-stream-analytics-with-reference-data/) and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842809/stream-analytics-job-deployed-as-azure-resource-manager-arm-template).

Answer (score 0):

The `outputStartMode` property should only be utilized when it is desired that the job be started immediately upon creation. If this property is absent, the default is `JobStartTime`.

1.When you set `outputStartMode` as `JobStartTime` and start immediately you do not need to set `outputStartMode` and `outputStartTime`.

```
"properties": {
    "sku": {
         "name": "Standard"
           },
     "eventsOutOfOrderPolicy": "Adjust",
     ........
```

2.When you want to set custom `outputStartTime`, you could set `outputStartMode` as `CustomTime`. And add at least one input defined. You could refer to this article about [StreamInputDataSourceProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.streamanalytics/2016-03-01/streamingjobs#streaminputdatasourceproperties).

```
"properties": {
    "sku": {
         "name": "Standard"
           },
    "outputStartMode": "CustomTime",
    "outputStartTime": "2020-03-10T10:49:29.56Z",
    "inputs": [
     {
         "name": "string",
         "properties": {
              "type": "string",
              "datasource": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "properties": {
                   }
               },
               "serialization": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "properties": {
                   }
               }
          }
      }
  ],
  ......
```

Answer (score 0):

currently the Azure Resource Template for Stream Analytics generated from Azure portal has a known issue and cannot be used to deploy the job. Can you try follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/resource-manager-export) to export the Azure Resource Template which can be used for deployment?

Comment: Thank you @JieSu. This week I will try the guide you sent me